# Postgresql select from a table and additional column

Tags: postgresql

Hello I have a table called "cars" and column car_name which is String.How can I select everything from cars and select the last 4 chars of car_name in one table?I know how to select the last 4 chars of a column by SUBSTRING(car_name,1,4)

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 1):

You can use simple query:

```
SELECT car_name, substring(car_name from '....$') AS car_sub AS car_sub FROM cars;
```

Or

```
SELECT car_name, right(car_name, 4) AS car_sub FROM cars;
```